# CRM 2011 Homepage Grid Ribbon enable rule doesn't work

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

I have a custom button in Activity homepage grid ribbon. I have an enable rule that calls a Javascript function. This rule doesn't seem to be working - it's not calling the Javascript function, I've put an alert to verify this. When I test my javascript function by calling from a Form OnLoad, everything looks fine.

So i'm guessing that the Homepage ribbon is not loading the js library somehow ? Has anyone come across this before ? 
Please help.

```xml
<EnableRule Id="RRM.activitypointer.HomepageGrid.RunReport">
    <CustomRule Library="RRM_/Script/Common/Main.js" FuncionName="RRM.Common.enableRunReport"></CustomRule>
</EnableRule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution. 
A couple of things
1. The way the webresource is called. Changing the rule to something like below worked

```
<CustomRule Library="$webresource:RRM_/Script/Common/Main.js" .. >
```

2. Loading the dependent webresources (since this button is not on a form). Adding dummy custom rules to call the dependent webresources fixed it

```
<CustomRule Library="$webresource:name" Functionname="isNAN"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, is `FunctionName` instead of `FuncionName`

Comment: sorry I think it might have been a typo. My ribbonXml has the correct syntax.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <EnableRule Id="RRM.activitypointer.HomepageGrid.RunReport">
    <CustomRule Library="$webresource:name" Functionname="isNAN"/>
    <CustomRule Library="RRM_/Script/Common/Main.js" Functionname="RRM.Common.enableRunReport"></CustomRule>
    </EnableRule>
```